# Inamax Wireless Adapter not working

Tags: wifi, hardware

My apologies for being a n00b but I am dusting my linux back off after many years on Windows and exploring Elementary OS. I like what I see so far but I cannot get my wireless adapter to work. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Found the way to fix it!!! https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2394372

Comment: can you post it like an answer of your question, and later mark it like the one that helps you in order your question to become resolved into stack exchange system?